# Servicenow database view left join working but not producing desired result

Tags: servicenow

In ServiceNow, I have Plans under 'sn_bcp_plan' table and Plan Asset under 'sn_bcp_plan_asset' table which stores reference to CI 'cmdb_ci_service_discovered' table.

Each plan will have one Plan asset. Through plan asset table, I can identify App service which is used for that Plan record. Now, Each plan will have a template which can be wither 'DR' or 'BV'. this is again stored in Plan table field called 'template'.

For example, CI Name: App Service 1, there can be either 'DR' Plan or 'BV' Plan or both available. So Plan record will look like

```
1. Plan - DR
      a. Plan Asset - App Service 1
2. Plan - BV
      a. Plan Asset - App Service 1
```

Now, I have a report widget for DR Plan, and BV Plan which is showing whether the app service is having a DR Plan or BV Plan. If yes, then it is grouped by Plan State field.

I have created a database view to join 3 tables (LEFT JOIN) for reporting purpose. see image below.
[image: database join]

This is the sample report widget. see image below.

[image: report widgets]

Question:  I have 100 App service, in total the report widget for DR should show 100 for and for BV should show 100. doesnt matter what the state is, but the count should match against the app service count.

```
1. Plan - DR 
   a. Plan asset record (80 records)
Report should show:  80 available, 20 not available
2. Plan - BV
   a. Plan asset record (50 records)
Report should show: 50 available, 50 not available


What actually report shows currently for BV widget: 50 available, 20 not available.
```

Not sure what's going on and how to resolve this. the report conditions are

For DR:
[image: DR report conditions]

For BV:
[image: BV report conditions]

your help will be much appreciated. TIA.